# C: function pointer to functions returning enums

Tags: c, function, pointers, types, enums

In C language,using IAR compiler for Cortex uC. Suppose you have three functions like:

```
Type_enum_1 get_parameter_alpha(void);
Type_enum_2 get_parameter_beta(void);
Type_enum_3 get_parameter_gamma(void);
```

I would like to know if it's possible to declare a function pointer that can be assigned to each of the above functions. I've tried using:

```
uint8_t (*getter_ptr)(void)
```

or

```
void (*getter_ptr)(void)
```

but no way the compiler accepts the assignment

```
getter_ptr = get_parameter_alpha
```

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: if you want to declare a single function pointer type that may return different values from three different enums, without a hint as to which enum is being returned in each case, then all I can say is "if there you go, only pain will you find."

Comment: You cannot use 1 for 3 different enum types. You will face warnings or errors.

Comment: @tilz0R i'll try. but how should i declare getter_ptr to make it work?

Comment: For functions which returns `Type_enum_1` declare it like this: `typedef Type_enum_1 (*type_enum_1_ptr)(void)` and then use it: `type_enum_1_ptr funcptr = myfunc` and to get response value `Type_enum_1 retval = funcptr();`

Comment: uhm... you are already declaring that pointer to be Type_enum_1 , i need more "flexibility"

Comment: Then the option is to use one function and pass `void*` as first parameter and `type` as second to know what enum you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type is part of the function's signature, therefore with a compiler that does not treat enums sloppily you won't be able to declare a function pointer type that covers all three functions as long as `Type_enum_1`, `Type_enum_2` and `Type_enum_3` do not happen to be identical.

What you could do, however, is make use of the fact that `enum`s are basically a different way to look at an integer, so as a workaround you could implement three proxy functions

```
int get_parameter_alpha_proxy(void) { return (int)get_parameter_alpha(); }
int get_parameter_beta_proxy(void) { return (int)get_parameter_beta(); }
int get_parameter_gamma_proxy(void) { return (int)get_parameter_gamma(); }
```

These three *can* be assigned to a point of type `int (*getter_ptr)(void)` - however the interpretation of the returned integer value will not be straightforward if the three enums involved have overlapping/ambiguous values (which would most of the time be the case).

Answer (score 1):

If your functions return different types, declare different `typedefs`for each of them.

```
Type_enum_1 get_parameter_alpha(void);
Type_enum_2 get_parameter_beta(void);
Type_enum_3 get_parameter_gamma(void);
```

Typedefs:

```
typedef Type_enum_1 (*enum_1_ptr)(void);
typedef Type_enum_2 (*enum_2_ptr)(void);
typedef Type_enum_3 (*enum_3_ptr)(void);
```

Declare pointers to functions:

```
enum_1_ptr e1ptr = get_parameter_alpha;
enum_2_ptr e2ptr = get_parameter_beta;
enum_3_ptr e3ptr = get_parameter_gamma;
```

Call them when you need:

```
Type_enum_1 res1 = e1ptr();
Type_enum_2 res2 = e2ptr();
Type_enum_3 res3 = e3ptr();
```

Comment: thanks, but this can't help me. You are declaring three function pointers, but i would like to use just one for all my getter functions

Comment: I got your point. Then the option is to do with proxy as answer before me. Keep in mind that then you have to be really careful with casting and interpretation what result you are expecting. Just like `void *` problems where you don't know what type of data you got. Be careful!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement some manner of generic inheritance model, for example:

```
typedef union
{
  Type_enum_1 e1;
  Type_enum_2 e2;
  Type_enum_3 e3;
} Type_enum_t;

typedef Type_enum_t  type_enum_func_t  (void);
```

Then declare the functions according to this template.

```
Type_enum_t get_parameter_alpha(void);
Type_enum_t get_parameter_beta(void);
Type_enum_t get_parameter_gamma(void);
```

They will still return their own specific type by setting the correct member of the union.

You can then declare a function pointer like this:

```
type_enum_func_t* fptr = get_parameter_alpha;
```